# in solaris how to draw table using awk command

Tags: awk, solaris

I have below data named atp.csv file....

```
Date_Time,M_ID,N_ID,Status,Desc,AMount,Type
2015-01-05 00:00:00 076,1941321748,BD9010423590206,200,Transaction Successful,2000,PRETOP
2015-01-05 00:00:00 077,1941323504,BD9010423590207,351,Transaction Successful,5000,PRETOP
2015-01-05 00:00:00 078,1941321743,BD9010423590205,200,Transaction Successful,1500,PRETOP
2015-01-05 00:00:00 391,1941323498,BD9010500000003,200,Transaction Successful,1000,PRETOP
```

i used below command

```
awk -F',' '{print $4}' atp.csv|sort|uniq -c
```

out put is:

```
3 200
1 351
```

but i want like below

```
-----------
| 3 | 200 |
-----------
| 1 | 351 |
-----------
```

Comment: interesting question, unfortunately no visible effort from your side... and BTW, why `awk`?

Comment: that's why i am asking your help...

Comment: .. because you're lazy to try something?

Comment: In fairness, OP _has_ tried to the point where they get the data, now just needs formatting.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `awk` yet again to tabulate it, something like (with the added `NR>1` filter to strip out the header line):

```
pax$ awk -F',' 'NR>1{print $4}' atp.csv | sort | uniq -c | awk '
    BEGIN { div = "+-------+-------+"; print div }
    { printf("| %5d | %5d |\n",$1,$2); print div }'

+-------+-------+
|     3 |   200 |
+-------+-------+
|     1 |   351 |
+-------+-------+
```

If, instead of numbers, you have *strings,* you would use something like `%7s` in the format string for right-justified, or `%-7s` for left:

```
pax$ echo 'pax diablo
bob smith
loretta jones' | awk '
    BEGIN { div = "+-----------+-----------+"; print div }
    { printf ("| %9s | %-9s |\n", $1, $2);     print div}'
+-----------+-----------+
|       pax | diablo    |
+-----------+-----------+
|       bob | smith     |
+-----------+-----------+
|   loretta | jones     |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: thanks for help. but can you please let me know if i want to print text instead of number what will be the value value instead of %9d...

Comment: @Basudev, added that to the bottom of the answer.

Comment: again thanks.....but still one issue... Data is right sided alligned..how can i set that data will be left side alligned...

Comment: @Basudev, I covered that in the addendum. Use `%-9s` for left justification, as per the right hand column.

Answer (score 0):

Use GNU awk for inbuilt sorting (`PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"`):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = ","
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
}
NR>1 { cnt[$4]++ }
END {
    for (val in cnt) {
        width_v = length(val)
        width_c = length(cnt[val])
        max_wv = (max_wv > width_v ? max_wv : width_v)
        max_wc = (max_wc > width_c ? max_wc : width_c)
    }

    sep = sprintf("%*s", max_wv + max_wc + 7, "")
    gsub(/ /,"-",sep)
    print sep
    for (val in cnt) {
        printf "| %*s | %*s |\n", max_wc, cnt[val], max_wv, val
        print sep
    }
}
$ awk -f tst.awk file
-----------
| 3 | 200 |
-----------
| 1 | 351 |
-----------
```

Note that the above will size the cells of the table based on the calculated max width of the contents of each cell, you do not need to specify it.

And before you say "but I'm on Solaris and don't have gawk" - just get it. It has a vast array of incredibly useful features, it will save you a lot of time over using any of the awks that come with Solaris.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [ftable](https://github.com/tlopo/ftable) it's a monolithic perl script with no external dependencies other than perl core.

Just download make it executable and run (you may have to change your shee bang depending where your perl instalation is)

**In Action:**

```
$ echo $'3 200\n1 351' | ftable -F '\s'
+---+-----+
| 3 | 200 |
+---+-----+
| 1 | 351 |
+---+-----+
```